# If I am using onclick to a button why it redirects me to the same page i am in (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs

how to click on anchor tag in the card and redirects me to another page with more details of the current card example click on opens new tab with current (clicked) card details here is an api for item https://api.npoint.io/d275425a434e02acf2f7/News/0

snippets of code also a link that works https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-spence-1tl4y5?file=/src/App.js

my api https://api.npoint.io/d275425a434e02acf2f7 for rendering all items in cards

```
 filteredCat?.map((list) => {
              if (list.showOnHomepage === "yes") {
                const date = format(
                  new Date(list.publishedDate),
                  "EEE dd MMM yyyy"
                );
                const showCat = news.map((getid) => {
                  if (getid.id == list.categoryID) return getid.name;
                });
                //  const rec = list.publishedDate.sort((date1, date2) => date1 - date2);

                return (
                  <Card
                    className=" extraCard col-lg-3"
                    style={{ width: "" }}
                    id={list.categoryID}
                  >
                    <Card.Img
                      variant="top"
                      src={list.urlToImage}
                      alt="Image"
                    />
                    <Card.Body>
                      <Card.Title className="textTitle">
                        {list.title}
                      </Card.Title>
                      <Card.Text></Card.Text>
                      <small className="text-muted d-flex">
                        <FaRegCalendarAlt
                          className="m-1"
                          style={{ color: "#0aceff" }}
                        />
                        {date}
                      </small>

                      <div
                        style={{ color: "#0aceff" }}
                        className="d-flex justify-content-between"
                      >
                        <Button variant="" className={classes["btn-cat"]}>
                          {showCat}
                        </Button>
                        <div>
                          <FaRegHeart />
                          <FaLink />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </Card.Body>
                  </Card>
                );
              }
            })
          }
        </div>
      }
```

I tried this technique but it does direct me to the same page not the new tab with empty page !!

```
function handleClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = 'src/comp/newsitem';
}

function news() {
  return (
    <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me to redirect!
    </a>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React provides [SPA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA)s which means that you can load your content of different pages without any refresh or redirect. So no need to redirect to another page unless you really want to open the page in a new tab.

Also if you want to have multiple page paths, you should use [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom).

So first of all you should add your routes to your app. Add a pages.js file with this content:

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import News from './News';
import NewsItem from './NewsItem';

function Pages() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/news' element={<News />} />
        <Route path='/newsItem' element={<NewsItem />} />
        <Route path='/' element={<App />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default Pages;
```

And then import it to your index.js file:

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import Pages from "./Pages";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Pages />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

NewsItem file:

```js
function NewsItem() {
  return <div>News Item</div>;
}
export default NewsItem;
```

And finally when you want to navigate the News page, do this:

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```

```js
<Link to='/news' />
```

Or if you want to open in new tab:

```js
<Link to='/news' target='_blank' />
```

And for navigating to NewsItem page (without any **a** tag):

```js
<Link to="/newsItem">News Item</Link>
```

Comment: Okay that worked but The content in Newsitem that I want to go to doesnot apear it opens a blank page

Comment: In the codesandbox link that you've sent, the News.js is empty. Could you add the code ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-lake-s2qh1l?file=/src/App.js here is whaat I am doing tell me what is the problem plz

Comment: @FarahFahmy I edited my answer. Check the new one and please pick my answer as the correct answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help it worked but the second part of my question was how to map the current clicked item to be viewed in that NewItem page only to show the same card but the one I clicked only you can edit in codesandbox

Comment: @FarahFahmy Check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-ardinghelli-50ku6r?file=/src/News.js

Comment: can you specify which parts you added as when i added to my code it returned a blank page

Comment: SyntaxError
Unexpected end of JSON input
eval
/src/NewsItem.js:10:35
   7 | 
   8 | const fetchDataList = () => {
   9 |   return fetch(`https://api.npoint.io/d275425a434e02acf2f7/News/${params.id}`)
> 10 |     .then((response) => response.json())
     |                                 ^
  11 |     .then((data) => {
  12 |       console.log(data);
  13 |so this happened   when clicked the second card

Comment: @FarahFahmy I updated the code. Check it again (NewsItem.js). The problem you have is that the server returns 404 for id = 20 (and maybe some other ids).